# TraCI Exception Handling in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm trying to dynamically re-route vehicles to the current road of another vehicle – which will sometimes fail if a route does not exist.

`traciVehicle->changeTarget(…)` will throw a cRuntimeError, but so long as `debug-on-errors = true` in my omnetpp.ini, my try-catch block will be ignored and the simulation aborted.

Besides disabling this debug mode, is there another way to recover from TraCI errors?

(In a first test scenario with Python and without Veins, the SUMO simulation was able to continue running if `changeTarget` was wrapped in a try-except block.)